# How can I programmatically make sure a user has selected an option with AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: android, dialog, builder

In my android application, I have created a dialog box showing the user multiple options from a list.

I have used this class to do so: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

More specifically, I used setMultiChoiceItems

Now the options are displaying correctly and everything works well. However, I need to make sure that the user has actually selected one of these options and not immediately pressed the proceeding Button that I have set using setPositiveButton.

Is there a way I can programmatically make sure one or more of these options is picked? I will set up a quick if statement as well and even display a warning dialog if none of the options is picked.

Thank you and I apologize if this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to use the `DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener` to keep track of the user's selections. Initialize an array before you create the dialog and then every time the user makes/clears a selection then add/remove it from the array. Once the user hits the positive button check if the array is empty: if it is, they made no selections.